# How do I send serializable objects to another android application

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am fairly new to java and I have been experimenting on sending serializable objects across application. I am trying to set up 2 independent apps and have app A send a serialize object to app B via a broadcast but I am faced with an error like this java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.appA.UserConfig).

I have read several questions regarding this issue but I can't seem to find a specific answer about this or if this is possible. 
My only progress and understanding so far is if I declare the same/copy the class from App A to App B, App B should be able to read the serializable object right?

Currently this is my code for App A:

UserConfig.java:

```
public class UserConfig implements Serializable {
    public final String var1;
    public final String[] var2;
    public final Map<String, Object> var3;

    public UserConfig(Map<String, Object> map, String[] strArr, String str) {
        this.var3 = map;
        this.var2 = strArr;
        this.var1 = str;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.appA.action.userConfig");
intent.putExtra("userConfig", userConfig);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Similarly for App B, I have copied the UserConfig file:

UserConfig.java:

```
public class UserConfig implements Serializable {
    public final String var1;
    public final String[] var2;
    public final Map<String, Object> var3;

    public UserConfig(Map<String, Object> map, String[] strArr, String str) {
        this.var3 = map;
        this.var2 = strArr;
        this.var1 = str;
    }
}
```

MyReceiver.java:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            try{
                Serializable serializableExtra = intent.getSerializableExtra("userConfig");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.i("ERROR", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the current out put from the exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.appA.UserConfig)

Comment: [Relevant documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles#sdbp)

Comment: I have configured both applications with the same compileSdkVersion,  targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion in my build.gradle

Comment: Have you checked if the files are in correct packages? The error says `com.appA.UserConfig` but your intent is `com.appA.action.userConfig`

Comment: The error is pointing to the class in appA though and `com.appA.action.userConfig` is just the action I declared so I dont think so?